# Alignment of Ads in Scrollview in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, admob

I am trying to create a page on Android with Ads (using ad mob). Following code I am using for it:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView_relative_layout" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Primary Screen sssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssss s jkjkljlkjkljsjkjlkjskjkjkl jkljkljkl jkljlkj kljkljkl jkljlkjkljkl jkljlkjkljlkjlk jlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj jkljlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlk jlkjlkjlkjkljlkjlkj lkjlkjlkjklj kljlkjlkjlkjkljlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlk lkjlkjlkjlkjlkj jlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj lkjlkjlk lkjlkjlknigpoihgpoj k lkjcfhkl jiuvlk jkjhu hiuhjlkjliijv kjgjhhgkjjhlkkjk"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/SwitchToSecond"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Switch to Second Screen"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/adView_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But the problem is the ads are coming at top and bottom of the screen (that's what I want) but It's covering the text at the top and bottom of the text by ad sections (Even I scroll up or down).And I am unable to see texts

Please guide how to align texts and scroll view so that I can see all the text along with the ad view.

Find below my Activity.java code:

```
package com.abc.testapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.google.ads.*;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button screen2Button=null;
    //private AdView adView;
     private AdView adView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        screen2Button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SwitchToSecond);
        screen2Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
            Intent myIntent=new Intent(v.getContext(),SecondScreen.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        String s1 = getResources().getString(R.string.MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
     // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, s1);

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
      }
      super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: whtat is this???                 android:text="Primary Screen sssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssss s jkjkljlkjkljsjkjlkjskjkjkl jkljkljkl jkljlkj kljkljkl jkljlkjkljkl jkljlkjkljlkjlk jlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj jkljlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj

Comment: It's just a text so than I can have maximum scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/adView1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Primary Screen sssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssss s jkjkljlkjkljsjkjlkjskjkjkl jkljkljkl jkljlkj kljkljkl jkljlkjkljkl jkljlkjkljlkjlk jlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj jkljlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlk jlkjlkjlkjkljlkjlkj lkjlkjlkjklj kljlkjlkjlkjkljlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlk lkjlkjlkjlkjlkj jlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj lkjlkjlk lkjlkjlknigpoihgpoj k lkjcfhkl jiuvlk jkjhu hiuhjlkjliijv kjgjhhgkjjhlkkjk"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SwitchToSecond"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Switch to Second Screen"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

Edit: I think you should try just using a linear layout since you want something very linear (ad, then ScrollView, then ad). I have edited the xml above to reflect that. It is untested though, so you might need to tweak it a bit.

Edit 3: Added a second AdView above the ScrollView to meet the requirement of one AdView at the top and one AdView at the bottom. Changed back to a RelativeLayout so that one AdView can be aligned at the top and one aligned at the bottom.

Comment: Thanx for reply, but it's giving runtime error:  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Comment: That error is not something I would have expected. Did you change anything else? Usually that happens if you tried to cast a RelativeLayout view as a Button somewhere in your activity. Have also tried cleaning the project? In Eclipse, Project -> Clean...

Comment: I tried clean option, but didn't work. Can you please look into my Java code? I suspect there is something missed out there.

Comment: Now I am getting one more issue... In the page only ads (at the top and at the bottom) showing up. Nothing else. I have posted the modified code above.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your Java code, so if you still get the crash you will have to post the whole logcat trace for me to see what might be going wrong. I have edited my answer with my guess as to why you might be having nothing else show up.

Comment: Thanx I am not getting any error, but my requirement is the 2 ad banners should come at the top and the bottom of the screen as fixed bar, and within those 2 bars entire scroll view and it's content should appear and user scan scroll up or down to see entire content. Which is not possible in case of linear lay out.

Comment: Okay, I edited the answer again. You should use a RelativeLayout and define two AdViews in XML, with one aligned to the top, then the ScrollView marked as below the first AdView, then the second AdView, marked as aligned with the parent on the bottom. You will have to not add an AdView in your Activity programmatically if you are going to define both in XML instead.